# Error in three.js : camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I am using three.js and the scene is not rendering. I am getting following errors in console:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///F:/Study/3rd%20Sem/ES%20XXX%20-20Intro%20to%20Computer%20Graphics/Stick%20Baddy/images/crate.jpg may not be loaded.
```

Here are some of my code snippets:

Camera:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // Create a Three.js scene object
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

Light:

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add(light);
```

Adding a cube:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(stickLenX, 20, 20);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/crate.jpg', {}, function() { renderer.render(scene); }) } ); 
var myStick = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // Create a mesh based on the specified geometry (myStick) and material (normal).
scene.add(myStick);  // at (0,0,0)
```

Rendering:

```
var render = function () {
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

move();

renderer.render(scene, camera); // Each time we change the position of the cube object, we must re-render it.
    requestAnimationFrame(render); 
};
render();
```

It works fine with `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()`
Like

```
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
```

In my code, there are other cubes and spheres, too. Could any of them be causing the problem? Please can anybody mention what could be the problem?

--------UPDATE:----------

Running the file with Wampserver worked. What is the reason for that and how to make it work without server?

Comment: could you put the code live, jsfiddle or just otherwise? i could give a shot at debugging but would prefer to see it with the debugger and not just read copy-pasted code. (no guarantees that would find the prob but would certainly help others too :)

Comment: @antont I opened the file in Wampserver in chrome and it is working. I guess it was a problem of browser. In my computer, it is not without server in any browser (firefox, chrome and IE). But in another computer, it is working in firefox. Any idea what browser issue could be in my firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using ImageUtils.loadTexture and PlaneGeometry.

```
            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 300, 1, 1 );
            geometry.vertices[0].uv  =  new THREE.Vector2( 0 , 0 );
            geometry.vertices[1].uv  =  new THREE.Vector2( 2, 0 );
            geometry.vertices[2].uv  =  new  THREE.Vector2( 2, 2 );
            geometry.vertices[3].uv  =  new  THREE.Vector2( 0, 2 );

            texture     =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("text.png",null,function(t){

            });
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ( {map: texture} );
            var mesh     = new THREE.Mesh ( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace the material.map with：
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/crate.jpg')